# How to Render SVG image format with Java API

Tags: java, svg

Is there any way to render SVG format image using the Java API, or is there any other Java API that I can use to render this image format. I found the [Apache Batik framework](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/); are there any other frameworks that do this?

Comment: http://java.net/projects/svgsalamander/sources/svn/show/trunk?rev=156

Comment: While huge, I've found Apache Batik to be the most functional.

Answer (score 2):

**JFreeSVG** has an [SVGGraphics2D](http://www.jfree.org/jfreesvg/javadoc/org/jfree/graphics2d/svg/SVGGraphics2D.html) implementation.

Comment: JFreeSVG can only output SVG documents, it cannot render existing SVG files within Java application. You draw on `SVGGraphics2D` and once done generate SVG document via `getSVGDocument()` method.